# Convert inline-assembly from Intel to AT&T syntax

Tags: c, sse, inline-assembly

The code below multiplies arrays `arr1` with `arr2` using SSE and puts result to `arr3`. Arrays have `count` elements. `arr1`, `arr2` and `arr3` have type `float*`. The problem is that the compiler doesn't support Intel syntax. How does this code look like in AT&T syntax?

Compiler is GCC 4.4.7.

```
__asm__ volatile (
    ".intel_syntax noprefix \n\t"
    "loop:                  \n\t"
    "movups xmm0, [eax+edx] \n\t"
    "movups xmm1, [ebx+edx] \n\t"
    "mulps xmm0, xmm1       \n\t"
    "movups [ecx+edx], xmm0 \n\t"
    "sub edx, 16            \n\t"
    "jnz loop               \n\t"
    :
    : "a"(arr1), "b"(arr2), "c"(arr3), "d"(count)
    : "xmm0", "xmm1"
);
```

Comment: compile it with `-masm=intel`, gcc offers supports for the Intel syntax, the thing is that it's simply not the default syntax for asm code.

Comment: Add returning to AT&T syntax as final asm clause. It should compile successfully. Then, you can use `objdump -d` to see how it looks in AT&T.

Comment: You'd be better off rewriting this short code using intrinsic functions. Same performance, more portable and easier on the eyes.

Comment: @egur yes, prepending `_mm_` to everything makes it a lot easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 0):

```
__asm__ volatile (
    "loop:                          \n\t"
    "subq $0x10, %%rdx              \n\t"
    "movups (%%rax,%%rdx), %%xmm0   \n\t"
    "movups (%%rbx,%%rdx), %%xmm1   \n\t"
    "mulps %%xmm1, %%xmm0           \n\t"
    "movups %%xmm0, (%%rcx,%%rdx)   \n\t"
    "jnz loop                       \n\t"
    :
    : "a"(arr1), "b"(arr2), "c"(arr3), "d"(count)
    : "xmm0", "xmm1"
);
```

`arr1`, `arr2` and `arr3` are 8-byte pointers and count is 8-byte integer, so registers are `r_x`